# Get a color value within a gradient based on a value

Tags: c#, wpf, gradient

Suppose I have the following gradient:

- Start (0): Green (0, 255, 0)
- Center (0.5): Orange (255, 165, 0)
- End (1): Red (255, 0, 0)

Is there now a calculation or an existing function to read a color value from this gradient based on a value that changes every second?

As a thought of mine: One could, e.g. in Photoshop, create an image, say 100px wide and 1px high. Now I lay a color gradient with the values and points mentioned above over the complete surface. The value, over which I want to get the color, is also only between the int values 0 and 100. So I could load this image into a variable or so (without displaying it in the UI) and get the color based on my value with a "GetPixel" function, so if e.g. the value is 50, I would get orange, because the 50th pixel in the image corresponds to orange. This would be a possibility that is plausible and (theoretically) easy to program.

But now the value changes every second. And I think I read somewhere that the GetPixel function is relatively slow. Of course I could just program it out now (which I'll probably do afterwards for testing purposes), but it seems to me to be very resource intensive. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: If you have a simple linear gradient in RGB from Start to Center and Center to End, you can simply compute the new RGB values by linear interpolation for each color, based on whether it is above or below Center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple linear interpolation between the colors in the RGB space using `System.Drawing.Color` to hold the colors:

```
public int LinearInterp(int start, int end, double percentage) => start + (int)Math.Round(percentage * (end - start));
public Color ColorInterp(Color start, Color end, double percentage) =>
    Color.FromArgb(LinearInterp(start.A, end.A, percentage),
                   LinearInterp(start.R, end.R, percentage),
                   LinearInterp(start.G, end.G, percentage),
                   LinearInterp(start.B, end.B, percentage));
public Color GradientPick(double percentage, Color Start, Color Center, Color End) {
    if (percentage < 0.5)
        return ColorInterp(Start, Center, percentage / 0.5);
    else if (percentage == 0.5)
        return Center;
    else
        return ColorInterp(Center, End, (percentage - 0.5)/0.5);
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
var Start = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0);
var Center = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 165, 0);
var End = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);

var Pick = GradientPick(0.75, Start, Center, End);
```

Comment: Very nice, it works wonderfully!
And definitely better than loading an image and reading its pixels. :P
Thanks !